How to handle accessibility for HIghChartView graph and it's sub elements for native android
I've implemented HighChartView in android using JavaScript where I'm plotted ting my dynamic data into graph form now I want to handle the accessibility for graph and for all the plotted view for which screen reader or Talkback should announce the view and its description.
got some handy solution for this link
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/accessibility/accessibility-module but it did not work.

HIAccessibility hiAccessibility = new HIAccessibility();
hiAccessibility.setEnabled(true);
options.setAccessibility(hiAccessibility);

By setting new HIAccessibility().setEnabled(true) within the chart options, you can enable the accessibility module for the Highcharts chart in your Android application.
Please note that Highcharts for Android provides a Java API for chart configuration and interaction, so you do not need to directly include JavaScript  tags in your Android code.
Tried to apply this line which i got from https://www.highcharts.com/chat/gpt/
but screen reader in reading and focusing the description and its plotted view.

tried this solution but still did not work.
HIAccessibility accessibility = new HIAccessibility();
accessibility.setEnabled(true);
accessibility.setPoint(new HIAccessibility.HIPoint() {{
setDescriptionFormatter("function(point) { return 'The data point for ' + point.category + ' has a value of ' + point.y; }");
}});
options.setAccessibility(accessibility);

Hi, on Android you need to add plugin chartView.plugins = mutableListOf("accessibility").
